# How to add querystring to url via fetch (Web APIs)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, ecmascript-6, fetch

This is my code using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to call a server side endpoint

```
request     
  .get('/_api/get_data')    
  .query(`user_id=${userId}`)       
  .end((err, res) => {
```

This will issue a call to `http://server/_api/get_data?user_i=112223`

With [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), the code has become:

```
let payload = {
  user_id: userId,
}

let data = new FormData(payload)

let opts = {
  body: data,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
}

fetch('/_api/get_data', opts)
.then((res) => {
```

With this new code, however, the querystring is not attached to the url.

How can I accomplish this effect with `fetch`?

Comment: `fetch(\`/_api/get_data?user_id=${userId}\`, opts)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [sample in spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api)

If you want to work with URL query parameters:

```
var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url).then(/* … */)
```

So, seems you should pass to `fetch` just generated url, and can't config it after.

For consctruct query you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
var urlSearch = new URLSearchParams(),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431};
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => urlSearch.append(key, params[key]));
fetch("https://geo.example.org/api?"+urlSearch).then(/* … */);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like `superagent` is neater. Is there anything to gain from switching to `fetch`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong, as i understand, main defference fetch api from xmlhttprequest is using promise api, so seems if you already use some libs implement it you can hardly find anything gain